How can I resolve lag while writing Spring Boot with Eclipse?

I am a student majoring in coding in South Korea.
As shown in the picture, I am writing code using Spring Boot, but the message 'computing...' keeps popping up and the program lags...
It doesn't even disappear and obstructs my view.
I am using Eclipse version 22-06.
and This is the Spring Starter Project.
I have no idea how to deal with this, please help me TT
Increased vm allocated memory to 4096m.
I went to Windows -> Preferencs and turned off various features.

The current Eclipse version is 2024-03. You doing wrong by using an outdated Eclipse version and maybe also an outdated version of the Spring Tools plugin. Please upgrade and support the open source software you use by providing feedback on the latest version only.
